# Cocoa-Touch: UIImageView.image display vs UIImage drawInRect:. The former looks horrible compared to the latter when scaling images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have one app, a `UIImage*`.

I'm painting the image twice:

Once in a table cell, which I'm drawing manually for performance reasons, so it's getting pained with `[image drawInRect:CGRect..];`

The 2nd time it's in a `UIImageView`.

The image is approx 3x the size of the rect I'm painting in.
Both the `UIImageView` frame and the passed rect are the exact same dimension.
The `UIImageView` is set to scale to fill.

When painting with `drawInRect` I get a nicely scaled image.
When it gets painted by the UIImageView within a XIB, it gets scaled horribly (pixelated, doesn't look good).

I guess there is a way to apply a scaling filter, but I don't set it before calling `drawInRect`, and there's no option to set it for the `UIImageView` in IB.

What do I have to do to get the same nice picture in the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Define "scaled horribly."  Does the aspect ratio get skewed?  Is it becoming pixellated?  What's happening?

Comment: @BJ Homer, it's pixelated, it doesn't look good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this link](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/), which is full of interesting information about manipulating image display -- I'm not sure if any of it will help you, but it can't hurt...

Comment: I'm positive about the frame sizes, they are exactly the same. What I meant in difference is after scaling, I'm not sure if AA is the right word to use, but the problem is that the UIImageView applies a not-so-good looking filter when resizing the image.

Comment: @your edit, I think setting the interpolation quality is exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: You are quite welcome.  I just discovered the interpolation settings a few days ago myself.  Interesting thing about developing for a new technology -- we learn together as we go.

Comment: Sorry to bring back a very old post but I'm having the same problem. Do you mean you set the interpolation quality with `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(c, kCGInterpolationHigh);` so that the UIImageView would scale nicely? Where did you call that? I tried from the parent view's drawRect: method and it seemed to have no effect.